# Yandex Translate Widget I can't overcome the size problem

Tags: html, size, translate, yandex

I struggled for hours or even days for this problem, but could not find it. I have included yandex translation in the system, but there are overflows in mobile view. There is no problem with the computer view. where am I doing wrong? What should i do?

I can also add 3-5 languages ​​instead of so many language options, remove all of them. If I can do it like this everything will be alright.

```
<div style="text-align: right">
    <div id="ytWidget"><script src="https://translate.yandex.net/website-widget/v1/widget.js?widgetId=ytWidget&pageLang=tr&widgetTheme=dark&autoMode=true" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</div>
```

system : https://translate.yandex.com/developers/website-widget

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does anyone have the answer?

Comment: I also recently encountered this problem. Here is my solution https://github.com/get-web/yandex-translate-custom-widget

Comment: Sorry I'm so late. As an alternative, I found the gtranslate.io system and I'm using it without any problems. You can use it if needed. By the way, thank you for your answer.